# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING)

Tags: php

$sql is where the error is found but i can't find a solution 
can any body help me fix this problem

//insert data to database
 $sql = "INSERT INTO user(user_country, travel_members) VALUES(:country, :members) WHERE user_id ='$_SESSION['user_session']'";

```
    $query = $DB_con->prepare($sql);

    $query->bindparam(':country', $country);
    $query->bindparam(':members', $members);
    $query->execute();
```

Comment: ... `user_id ='{$_SESSION['user_session']}'";`

Comment: You are using $_SESSION['user_session'] variable inside single quotes, which also has its own single quotes. You can simply use $_SESSION['user_session'] variable without any single quotes around it.

Comment: still same error nothing changes